# Self-hosted fax to email software

Tags: linux, email, fax

Requirements:

- I need to be able to receive fax messages without a fax machine.
- Fax messages should be forwarded to an email address.
- The software used should be self-hosted.
- The software used should be able to run on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I can vouch for [Hylafax](https://www.hylafax.org/):

You will need some sort of [hardware](https://www.hylafax.org/hardware-compatibility-list/) to receive the faxes.

Hylafax can receive the faxes and [email them in a format you can choose](https://www.hylafax.org/how-to/attachments/) (pdf, tif, ...).

It is already packaged for [many Linux distributions](https://www.hylafax.org/linux/).